# What is the eccentricity of the hyperbola given by $3x^2+7xy+2y^2-11x-7y+10=0$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> What is the eccentricity of the hyperbola given by the following equation? 
>   $$3x^2+7xy+2y^2-11x-7y+10=0$$

what i try

$$S = 3x^2+7xy+2y^2-11x-7y+10$$

$\displaystyle \frac{dS}{dx}=6x+7y-11=0$ and $\displaystyle \frac{dS}{dy}=7x+4y-7=0$

center of hyperbola is at $\displaystyle x = 1/5$ and $y=7/5$

put $x=X-1/5$ and $y=y-7/5$ into $S$

$\displaystyle 3\bigg(X-1/5\bigg)^2+7\bigg(X-1/5\bigg)\bigg(Y-7/5\bigg)+2\bigg(Y-7/5\bigg)^2-11\bigg(X-1/5\bigg)-7\bigg(Y-7/5\bigg)+10=0$

$3X^2+2Y^2+7XY+611=0$

How do i solve it help me please

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation of that hyperbola as follows:
$$
(x+2y-3)(3x+y-2)=-4.
$$
Lines $x+2y-3=0$ and $3x+y-2=0$ are then the asymptotes, forming between them an angle $\theta$ given by
$$
\cos\theta={(1,2)\cdot(3,1)\over|(1,2)|\cdot|(3,1)|}={1\over\sqrt2}.
$$
If $a$ and $b$ are the hyperbola semi-axes, the eccentricity $e$ is then given by
$$
e=\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2}=\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta/2)}={1\over\cos(\theta/2)}=\sqrt{2\over1+\cos\theta}=2\sqrt{1-1/\sqrt2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Aretino plesee explain me how i find $(x+2y-3)\cdot (3x+y-2)=-4$

Comment: I found it "by sight", but you can of course expand $(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)$ and compare the coefficients of the resulting polynomial with those of the given polynomial, with the exception of the constant coefficient, and thus find $a$, $b$ and  so on.